# comunicate between 2 windows with javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-site

Following problem:
I have one website which contains a huge number of data sheets, another website which contain a form to be filled out. I want to have a third windows, which contains a control script. The control script asks the user to enter the number of a datasheet, it then opens the datasheet from the website, reads the data and fills in the form on the second window. The user checks adds further information and clicks on the form to submit it.
Any idea if this is possible and if it is, how to achieve it ?
I now this is scross site scripting, but in this case it is, was the user needs
Thx a lot for any hint

Comment: They're on the same domain, aren't them?

Answer (score 2):

What about window.postMessage? See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage